# How to integrate HSQL DB with java application

Tags: java, hsqldb, h2

I would like to integrate HSQL in my Java application for testing purposes. Is there any tutorial that describes in a simple way how to integrate it-I want to distribute it with my app. I'm not restricted to HSQL any other easier solution are welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: How about http://www.google.com/search?q=hsqldb+embedded

Comment: This doesn't show how to define tables and schemas I need all of that

Comment: Check the links here http://hsqldb.org/web/usagelinks.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your question is extremely broad and not really possible to answer, but I'll try anyway.

HSQLDB is not different to any other DBMS (except that it can run in the same process as your application - that is different e.g. to PostgreSQL).

Starting the database is described [in the first chapter of the manual](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html) including a chapter on how to [create a new database](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#running_newdb-sect)

Apart from that, just run your `CREATE TABLE` statements e.g. from within your application, the included [SqlTool](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/util-guide/sqltool-chapt.html) or any (JDBC based) SQL client that you like.

Deployment and integration into your application is described in the manual as well: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html.

The chapter "[Embedded Databases in Desktop Applications](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html#N13F83)" might also be interesting to you.

Comment: Perfect answer! Since you answer these kinds of broad questions, could you please tell me the answer to life, the universe, and everything? :)

Comment: @Lukas: `42` is the answer to life, universe and everything

Comment: @Horse: Why did I know I'd get that answer ;-)